# Delete lines in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I need to delete all the lines on a subplot, to then redraw them (i'm making a redraw function to be used when i add/remove some lines)
How do I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the `Axes` object stored, you reference each line by the `lines` member:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(line one)
ax.plot(line two)
# plot
ax.lines.pop(0) # removes the first line
# plot again
```

Answer (score 0):

`ax.lines` is just a Python list

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.lines.clear()
```