# How to remove lines in a Matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

How can I remove a line (or lines) of a matplotlib axes in such a way as it actually gets garbage collected and releases the memory back?  The below code appears to delete the line, but never releases the memory (even with explicit calls to `gc.collect()`)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy
a = numpy.arange(int(1e7))
# large so you can easily see the memory footprint on the system monitor.
fig = pyplot.Figure()
ax  = pyplot.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
lines = ax.plot(a) # this uses up an additional 230 Mb of memory.
# can I get the memory back?
l = lines[0]
l.remove()
del l
del lines
# not releasing memory
ax.cla() # this does release the memory, but also wipes out all other lines.
```

So is there a way to just delete one line from an axes and get the memory back?
[This potential solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732578/delete-lines-in-matplotlib) also does not work.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I'm showing that a combination of `lines.pop(0)` `l.remove()` and `del l` does the trick.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy, weakref
a = numpy.arange(int(1e3))
fig = pyplot.Figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
lines = ax.plot(a)

l = lines.pop(0)
wl = weakref.ref(l)  # create a weak reference to see if references still exist
#                      to this object
print wl  # not dead
l.remove()
print wl  # not dead
del l
print wl  # dead  (remove either of the steps above and this is still live)
```

I checked your large dataset and the release of the memory is confirmed on the system monitor as well.

Of course the simpler way (when not trouble-shooting) would be to pop it from the list and call `remove` on the line object without creating a hard reference to it:

```
lines.pop(0).remove()
```

Comment: I ran your code and I got:
[8:37pm]@flattop:~/Desktop/sandbox>python delete_lines.py 
<weakref at 0x8dd348c; to 'Line2D' at 0x8dd43ec>
<weakref at 0x8dd348c; to 'Line2D' at 0x8dd43ec>
<weakref at 0x8dd348c; to 'Line2D' at 0x8dd43ec>
I'm using matplotlib version 0.99.1.1 in ubuntu 10.04

Comment: @David Morton  I just downgraded to 0.99.1 and now I reproduce your problem.  I guess I can only recommend upgrading to 1.0.1.  There were a *lot* of bugfixes since 0.99.x

Comment: The issue here is likely an issue of references hanging around when they shouldn't be. I would bet that the OP was using IPython to test things out. See my answer.

Comment: I think the behavior has been updated. In Matplotlib 3.5.3, the line gets removed after either poping it from `ax.lines` or finding it and calling `l.remove()`. Attempting to call `remove()` on the line after poping raises `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`

Answer (score 95):

This is a very long explanation that I typed up for a coworker of mine.  I think it would be helpful here as well.  Be patient, though.  I get to the real issue that you are having toward the end.  Just as a teaser, it's an issue of having extra references to your `Line2D` objects hanging around.

**WARNING:** One other note before we dive in.  If you are using IPython to test this out, IPython keeps references of its own and not all of them are weakrefs.  So, testing garbage collection in IPython does not work.  It just confuses matters.

Okay, here we go.  Each `matplotlib` object (`Figure`, `Axes`, etc) provides access to its child artists via various attributes.  The following example is getting quite long, but should be illuminating.

We start out by creating a `Figure` object, then add an `Axes` object to that figure.  Note that `ax` and `fig.axes[0]` are the same object (same `id()`).

```
>>> #Create a figure
>>> fig = plt.figure()
>>> fig.axes
[]

>>> #Add an axes object
>>> ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

>>> #The object in ax is the same as the object in fig.axes[0], which is 
>>> #   a list of axes objects attached to fig 
>>> print ax
Axes(0.125,0.1;0.775x0.8)
>>> print fig.axes[0]
Axes(0.125,0.1;0.775x0.8)  #Same as "print ax"
>>> id(ax), id(fig.axes[0])
(212603664, 212603664) #Same ids => same objects
```

This also extends to lines in an axes object:

```
>>> #Add a line to ax
>>> lines = ax.plot(np.arange(1000))

>>> #Lines and ax.lines contain the same line2D instances 
>>> print lines
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0xce84bd0>]
>>> print ax.lines
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0xce84bd0>]

>>> print lines[0]
Line2D(_line0)
>>> print ax.lines[0]
Line2D(_line0)

>>> #Same ID => same object
>>> id(lines[0]), id(ax.lines[0])
(216550352, 216550352)
```

If you were to call `plt.show()` using what was done above, you would see a figure containing a set of axes and a single line:

[image: A figure containing a set of axes and a single line]

Now, while we have seen that the contents of `lines` and `ax.lines` is the same, it is very important to note that the object referenced by the `lines` variable is not the same as the object reverenced by `ax.lines` as can be seen by the following:

```
>>> id(lines), id(ax.lines)
(212754584, 211335288)
```

As a consequence, removing an element from `lines` does nothing to the current plot, but removing an element from `ax.lines` removes that line from the current plot.  So:

```
>>> #THIS DOES NOTHING:
>>> lines.pop(0)

>>> #THIS REMOVES THE FIRST LINE:
>>> ax.lines.pop(0)
```

So, if you were to run the second line of code, you would remove the `Line2D` object contained in `ax.lines[0]` from the current plot and it would be gone.  Note that this can also be done via `ax.lines.remove()` meaning that you can save a `Line2D` instance in a variable, then pass it to `ax.lines.remove()` to delete that line, like so:

```
>>> #Create a new line
>>> lines.append(ax.plot(np.arange(1000)/2.0))
>>> ax.lines
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0xce84bd0>,  <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0xce84dx3>]
```

[image: A figure containing a set of axes and two lines]

```
>>> #Remove that new line
>>> ax.lines.remove(lines[0])
>>> ax.lines
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0xce84dx3>]
```

[image: A figure containing a set of axes and only the second line]

All of the above works for `fig.axes` just as well as it works for `ax.lines`

Now, the real problem here.  If we store the reference contained in `ax.lines[0]` into a `weakref.ref` object, then attempt to delete it, we will notice that it doesn't get garbage collected:

```
>>> #Create weak reference to Line2D object
>>> from weakref import ref
>>> wr = ref(ax.lines[0])
>>> print wr
<weakref at 0xb758af8; to 'Line2D' at 0xb757fd0>
>>> print wr()
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xb757fd0>

>>> #Delete the line from the axes
>>> ax.lines.remove(wr())
>>> ax.lines
[]

>>> #Test weakref again
>>> print wr
<weakref at 0xb758af8; to 'Line2D' at 0xb757fd0>
>>> print wr()
<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xb757fd0>
```

The reference is still live!  Why?  This is because there is still another reference to the `Line2D` object that the reference in `wr` points to.  Remember how `lines` didn't have the same ID as `ax.lines` but contained the same elements?  Well, that's the problem.

```
>>> #Print out lines
>>> print lines
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0xce84bd0>,  <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0xce84dx3>]

To fix this problem, we simply need to delete `lines`, empty it, or let it go out of scope.

>>> #Reinitialize lines to empty list
>>> lines = []
>>> print lines
[]
>>> print wr
<weakref at 0xb758af8; dead>
```

So, the moral of the story is, clean up after yourself.  If you expect something to be garbage collected but it isn't, you are likely leaving a reference hanging out somewhere.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. I'm plotting thousands of maps, each with a scatter plot over top of a world map projection. They were taking 3 seconds each! By reusing the figure with the map already drawn and popping the resulting collection from ax.collections I got it down to 1/3 of a second. Thanks!

Comment: I think this is no longer necessary in current versions of mpl.  The artist have a `remove()` function which will clean them out of the mpl side of things, and then you only need to keep track of your references.

Comment: Huh, any idea what version of matplotlib this change same out in?

Comment: Found this to be useful when using a bunch of plots in a matplotlib animation. Otherwise, you end up with a very large amount of memory in use. Now to make this thing faster.

Answer (score 18):

I've tried lots of different answers in different forums. I guess it depends on the machine your developing. But I haved used the statement

```
ax.lines = []
```

and works perfectly. I don't use `cla()` cause it deletes all the definitions I've made to the plot

Ex.

```
pylab.setp(_self.ax.get_yticklabels(), fontsize=8)
```

but I've tried deleting the lines many times. Also using the weakref library to check the reference to that line while I was deleting but nothing worked for me.

Hope this works for someone else =D

Comment: The issue here is likely an issue of references hanging around when they shouldn't be.  I would bet that the OP was using IPython to test things out.  See my answer.

Comment: it is not possible to set an attribute in matplotlib 3.5.3

Answer (score 10):

Hopefully this can help others: The above examples use `ax.lines`.
With more recent mpl (3.3.1), there is `ax.get_lines()`.
This bypasses the need for calling `ax.lines=[]`

```
for line in ax.get_lines(): # ax.lines:
    line.remove()
# ax.lines=[] # needed to complete removal when using ax.lines
```

Comment: This should be up further in the list because the other answers are really out of date and confusing.

Answer (score 6):

(using the same example as the guy above)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot
import numpy
a = numpy.arange(int(1e3))
fig = pyplot.Figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
lines = ax.plot(a)

for i, line in enumerate(ax.lines):
    ax.lines.pop(i)
    line.remove()
```

Answer (score 2):

while you can remove any line with specific index in an axes as following:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)

axes = fig.axes  # = [ax1, ax2]

# add two lines to ax1
ax1.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 1, 20, 3, 40], lw=2, color='k', label='2 Hz')
ax1.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [15, 6, 25, 8, 45], lw=2, color='r', label='4 Hz')

# remove one line from ax1
ax1.lines[0].remove()  # remove the first line in ax1
# axes[0].lines[0].remove()  # equivalent to the line above
```

Comment: for the fifth line you can call the method `fig.get_axes()` alternatively.