# Matplotlib animation: vertical cursor line through subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, mouse-cursor

**[Solution has been added to the EDIT sections in this post]**

2 animated subplots are stacked vertically.

I would like to show a black vertical line through them according to the mouse position.

Up to now I can only completely mess the figure when moving the mouse...

How to clear the old vertical lines between updates?

(Just out of curiosity: since mouse movement control, my PC fan goes crazy when executing the code even without moving the mouse. Is mouse so "calculation expensive"?!?)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from time import sleep

val1 = np.zeros(100)         
val2 = np.zeros(100)      

level1 = 0.2
level2 = 0.5

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,1),(0,0))
lineVal1, = ax1.plot(np.zeros(100))
ax1.set_ylim(-0.5, 1.5)    

ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2,1),(1,0))
lineVal2, = ax2.plot(np.zeros(100), color = "r")
ax2.set_ylim(-0.5, 1.5)    


def onMouseMove(event):
  ax1.axvline(x=event.xdata, color="k")
  ax2.axvline(x=event.xdata, color="k")



def updateData():
  global level1, val1
  global level2, val2

  clamp = lambda n, minn, maxn: max(min(maxn, n), minn)

  level1 = clamp(level1 + (np.random.random()-.5)/20.0, 0.0, 1.0)
  level2 = clamp(level2 + (np.random.random()-.5)/10.0, 0.0, 1.0)

  # values are appended to the respective arrays which keep the last 100 readings
  val1 = np.append(val1, level1)[-100:]
  val2 = np.append(val2, level2)[-100:]

  yield 1     # FuncAnimation expects an iterator

def visualize(i):

  lineVal1.set_ydata(val1)
  lineVal2.set_ydata(val2)

  return lineVal1,lineVal2

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', onMouseMove)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, visualize, updateData, interval=50)
plt.show()
```

**Edit1**

As solved by Ophir:

```
def onMouseMove(event):
    ax1.lines = [ax1.lines[0]]
    ax2.lines = [ax2.lines[0]]
    ax1.axvline(x=event.xdata, color="k")
    ax2.axvline(x=event.xdata, color="k")
```

**Edit2**

In case there are more datasets in the same plot such as in:

```
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,1),(0,0))
lineVal1, = ax1.plot(np.zeros(100))
lineVal2, = ax2.plot(np.zeros(100), color = "r")
ax1.set_ylim(-0.5, 1.5)
```

each dataset's line is stored in `ax1.lines[]`:

- `ax1.lines[0]` is `lineVal1`
- `ax1.lines[1]` is `lineVal2`
- `ax1.lines[2]` is the vertical line if you already drew it.

This means `onMouseMove` has to be changed to:

```
def onMouseMove(event):
  ax1.lines = ax1.lines[:2] # keep the first two lines
  ax1.axvline(x=event.xdata, color="k") # then draw the vertical line
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace your `onMouseMove` with the following one:

(I used [How to remove lines in a Matplotlib plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981815/how-to-remove-lines-in-a-matplotlib-plot))

```
def onMouseMove(event):
  ax1.lines = [ax1.lines[0]]
  ax2.lines = [ax2.lines[0]]
  ax1.axvline(x=event.xdata, color="k")
  ax2.axvline(x=event.xdata, color="k")
```

Comment: Thank you Ophir. I could never have found it without your help.
Now it is perfectly logic.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of adding new `axvline`s to the plot you simply change the data of the existing one. You only need to store the return value of the `axvline` call to keep the handle on it. The data format is `([x, x], [0, 1])`, which can be changed using `set_data`.
(For axhlines the format is `([0, 1], [y, y])` by the way.)

Add the following global variables:

```
axvline1 = ax1.axvline(x=0., color="k")
axvline2 = ax2.axvline(x=0., color="k")
```

and change the conMouseMove handler to:

```
def onMouseMove(event):
  axvline1.set_data([event.xdata, event.xdata], [0, 1])
  axvline2.set_data([event.xdata, event.xdata], [0, 1])
```

A minor drawback is that you start with the vlines at x=0 from the start.

Full code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from time import sleep

val1 = np.zeros(100)         
val2 = np.zeros(100)      

level1 = 0.2
level2 = 0.5

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,1),(0,0))
lineVal1, = ax1.plot(np.zeros(100))
ax1.set_ylim(-0.5, 1.5)    

ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2,1),(1,0))
lineVal2, = ax2.plot(np.zeros(100), color = "r")
ax2.set_ylim(-0.5, 1.5)    

axvline1 = ax1.axvline(x=0., color="k")
axvline2 = ax2.axvline(x=0., color="k")


def onMouseMove(event):
  axvline1.set_data([event.xdata, event.xdata], [0, 1])
  axvline2.set_data([event.xdata, event.xdata], [0, 1])


def updateData():
  global level1, val1
  global level2, val2

  clamp = lambda n, minn, maxn: max(min(maxn, n), minn)

  level1 = clamp(level1 + (np.random.random()-.5)/20.0, 0.0, 1.0)
  level2 = clamp(level2 + (np.random.random()-.5)/10.0, 0.0, 1.0)

  # values are appended to the respective arrays which keep the last 100 readings
  val1 = np.append(val1, level1)[-100:]
  val2 = np.append(val2, level2)[-100:]

  yield 1     # FuncAnimation expects an iterator

def visualize(i):

  lineVal1.set_ydata(val1)
  lineVal2.set_ydata(val2)

  return lineVal1,lineVal2

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', onMouseMove)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, visualize, updateData, interval=50)
plt.show()
```