# Erasing previous data/plots in Julia (Plots.jl, GR backend)

Tags: animation, plot, julia, gif, ode

I have solved an ODE in Julia describing the motion of a particle, and I have saved the coordinates and respective time in an array. I would like to create an animated gif image of a plot with the particle along the solved trajectory, but to do that (the only way that I have come up) is to plot the position of the particle using `scatter`, and erase the previous position of the particle every moment. However I only know about `scatter!` which will add more particles to the plot rather than showing the change of particle position. So how can I erase the previous plot every iteration, or are there more clever ways to do this? And what about if I want to mark down the trajectory of the particle in earlier moments using plots?

Comment: Do you need to use Plots.jl?  Makie.jl is definitely better for this, since it will allow you to change the position of the scatter marker.

There is a (perhaps overcomplicated) example here:
https://simondanisch.github.io/ReferenceImages/gallery/differentialequations_path_animation/index.html

Comment: I had a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57829961/julia-plotting-delete-and-modify-existing-lines , switched to Makie as recommended and removing objects works just fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Erasing previous data is not possible with Plots.jl. The previous plot can be erased by using `plot` or `scatter` commands instead of `plot!` and `scatter!`. Here are some examples how animations can be created using the `@gif` macro (http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/animations/)

Create some dummy data:

```
using Plots

t = range(0, 4π, length = 100)
r = range(1, 0, length = 100)

x = cos.(t) .* r
y = sin.(t) .* r
```

Plot only the last current point in each step:

```
@gif for i in eachindex(x)
    scatter((x[i], y[i]), lims = (-1, 1), label = "")
end
```

[image]

Plot all previous steps with a marker at the current position:

```
@gif for i in eachindex(x)
    plot(x[1:i], y[1:i], lims = (-1, 1), label = "")
    scatter!((x[i], y[i]), color = 1, label = "")
end
```

[image]

The same as above with decreasing alpha for older steps (only showing the newest 10 steps):

```
@gif for i in eachindex(x)
    plot(x[1:i], y[1:i], alpha = max.((1:i) .+ 10 .- i, 0) / 10, lims = (-1, 1), label = "")
    scatter!((x[i], y[i]), color = 1, label = "")
end
```

[image]

Comment: Is it still impossible to erase data with Plots.jl?