# How to remove stemline(s) from a matplotlib stem plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is an example script to create a stem plot in matplotlib.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# returns 10 evenly spaced samples from 0.1 to 2*PI
x = np.linspace(0.1, 2 * np.pi, 10)

fig, ax = plt.subplots( figsize=(4.,3.), constrained_layout=True)
markerline, stemline, baseline = ax.stem(x, np.cos(x), '-.', use_line_collection=True)
markerline1, stemline1, baseline1 = ax.stem(x, np.cos(x*5), '-', use_line_collection=True)

plt.setp(baseline, color='black', linewidth=2)
plt.setp(baseline1, color='black', linewidth=2)
plt.setp( stemline, color="green" )
plt.setp( stemline1, color="red" )

plt.show()
```

Q1. After creating these plots, I would like to remove for example `markerline1`, `stemline1`, `baseline1`. How do I remove them?

Q2. If I would like to remove the entire stem plot from `ax` without affecting other settings of `ax`, how do I do so? I found that `ax.clear()` removes everything from `ax`.

According to matplotlib,

> UserWarning: In Matplotlib 3.3 individual lines on a stem plot will be
>   added as a LineCollection instead of individual lines.

Also, [LineCollection](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/collections_api.html?highlight=linecollection#matplotlib.collections.LineCollection) appears to have an attribute called `segment` that contains the x,y info of all the stem lines.

Q3. How do I get the `LineCollection` object from `ax` or `fig`? I am exploring if amending the `LineCollection` object is a method to answer my first question.

Comment: Q1: You can use obj.remove()` to remove objects from a plot after they have been plot, i.e `markerline1.remove()`, etc. More details here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981815/how-to-remove-lines-in-a-matplotlib-plot

This can be extended to Q2 by looping over all the objects you have on your plot if you named them before.

Comment: @Liris Thanks. `.remove()`  works when `use_line_collection=True` but not when `use_line_collection=False`. Pls put up your answer in the Answer Section so that I can accept it. cheers ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `obj.remove()` to remove objects from a plot after they have been plot, i.e `markerline1.remove()`, etc.

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981815/how-to-remove-lines-in-a-matplotlib-plot)

This can be extended to Q2 by looping over all the objects you have on your plot if you named them before.