# Plotting clearing the graph in for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I am plotting within a for loop. So that I get a new graph each iteration. Of course I want to clear the graph from the previous iteration. When I use `plt.cla()` the axis labels and title is also cleared. How can I just remove the graph but keep the axis labels and title?

```
for n in range(N):
    ax.plot(x[n],t) # plot  
    plt.savefig(f'fig_{n}.png') # save the plot
    plt.cla()
```

Comment: Define the title and labels before the loop then set them again?

Comment: Does [Matplotlib - How to remove a specific line or curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19569052/matplotlib-how-to-remove-a-specific-line-or-curve) answer your question?

Comment: How about [Delete lines in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732578/delete-lines-in-matplotlib)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9896338/2823755

Answer (score 0):

Try `plt.clf()` - [clear figure](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.clf.html)

```
for n in range(N):
    ax.plot(x[n],t) # plot  
    plt.savefig(f'fig_{n}.png') # save the plot
    plt.clf()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove lines at the bottom of the loop.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = np.arange(10)
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('foo')
ax.set_ylabel('wye')
ax.set_xlabel('EX')

for n in range(3):
    ln, = ax.plot(y*n)
    fig.savefig(f'fig{n}')
    ln.remove()
```